# Python internal database use

Tags: python, mysql, sql-server, database

Say I have a database of recipes that I have online, and I want to use this database in a program, but I want to store the information from the database internally to the program and only have to connect to the online database when I want to update, however I don't want my end-users to have to have a database(MySql, MSSQL, etc..) installed to their machine. What would be the best way to efficiently do this?

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/ is always handy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[sqlite](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html) is the most common way to use databases without a database server.